# Enter BIOS on superfast loading PC

Tags: windows-10, boot, ssd, bios

Problem is that I cannot enter the BIOS because the laptop I'm using has an SSD and it boots so fast that it skips the BIOS screen so I don't even get a chance to enter BIOS.

How could I get into the BIOS on some other way like an automated exe that auto enters it on startup or something,I even switched Fast Startup off and it didn't help.

EDIT

The laptop model is Toshiba Satellite L855-12v.

Here is what I already tried:

1)I tried to enter the BIOS by pressing EACH and EVERY of this keys:F1,F2,F8,F10,F11,F12,DEL;so far each key just makes the laptop beep and delays the booting with no damn chance to get in the BIOS.

2)I tried to enter the UEFI Firmware option through Advanced Startup but guess what the laptop has no UEFI so the option is not there.

Steps used to find that setting, just to be sure no one thinks I'm that retarded.

Go to the start menu
->Click Power
->Hold the SHIFT key
->Click Restart
->Wait until the advanced options show
->Click Troubleshoot
->Click Advanced Options
->Click UEFI Firmware Settings(THIS OPTION DOES NOT SHOW UP)
->Click Restart

3)I already disabled fast boot from the battery settings.

4)I tried booting up in Safe Mode,hoping it may delay it a bit, still no help.

5)I tried pulling out the battery and letting the laptop do a cold boot still no help.

Oh btw each and EVERY of those steps were done BEFORE asking here, I came here in the hope that I find help form true professionals, also I want to thank everyone who responded so far.

Comment: The BIOS is loaded from ROM, not disc, so the speed of the disc does not affect the length of time the BIOS screen is displayed. Check with the motherboard manual to see how to control this.

Comment: wait...ROM isn't the disc?then..

Comment: Just so. It is the BIOS that initiates the boot sequence. It will run whether or not a disc is attached. Using its boot settings you can choose to boot from the network, optical disc, USB drive, or even another on-board ROM.

Comment: BIOS loads from the motherboard not disk,right?...ok but still how do I get to the BIOS if I can't even see the bios screen(the laptop is not EFI so i cannot access UEFI Firmware option)

Comment: As I said, the motherboard manual will tell you this. I am using BIOS in the loose sense of whatever runs (from ROM) whenever the CPU is switched on. This may be UEFI firmware or legacy BIOS.

Comment: Giving the make and model of motherboard or computer would be helpful, please edit the original question and add more details.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I enter the BIOS on Windows 10?](http://superuser.com/questions/1016274/how-do-i-enter-the-bios-on-windows-10)

Answer (score 1):

Hold a certain key down while you turn it on. Which key depends on your motherboard. Often its F1 or a different function key.

If you can't find which key it is for your motherboard, you'll probably get it within a minute or two with trial and error. You won't break anything holding down the wrong key.

In the BIOS, you may find an option to delay booting up for a second or two.

Answer (score 1):

There is typically a setting in the BIOS that allows to skip that boot screen, it's probably set to 'Skip'. Once you are in, you can switch it off.

To get in, look up your motherboard in the internet, or just try to hold a key down when booting. Typical candidates are F1, F2, F8, F10, F12, ESC. Just keep trying, you have nothing to lose.

(The sense of the setting is basically 'Don't waste my time on every boot by showing me that screen for two seconds, I know how to get in the BIOS')