# Lenovo T420 no BIOS/UEFI

Tags: windows-10, boot, windows-8, laptop, bios

I recently found this Lenovo T420 (Core i5-2520M, 8GB, 500GB) in my cupboard. It had Windows 8 Pro. I updated this to Windows 10 a couple of days ago. Now, when I boot the laptop, instead of showing the ThinkPad screen like it always did, it now just shows the Windows 10 logo, with some swirling dots. This is fine, however I cannot access the BIOS through this screen, no matter how quickly after pressing the power button I hit Enter (to 'Interrup normal startup'), or press the dedicated BIOS key (F12, if I'm not mistaken). I can get to the UEFI through Advanced Startup, but this is annoying for everyday use.
I have tried finding an option to change this back in the UEFI but I can't find it. I have done a full UEFI update for this machine, and I have gone back to Windows 8 (the Windows Logo has appeared here as well, plus Win8 is no longer supported) and then updated back to Win10. Please help, I'd quite like to be able to get to the setup on this machine.

Comment: It likely has UEFI, not BIOS, as the BIOS splash screen takes a few seconds to boot through, whereas UEFI can be as little as <2s. On some laptops, you have to be extremely quick, repeatedly pressing whatever `F` key is for the firmware settings as soon as the power button is pressed

Comment: Check the alternative answers on the duplicate. Windows 10 has a special menu option that should reboot directly into the BIOS/UEFI menu. https://superuser.com/a/1016281/19943

Comment: On Windows 8+ devices, you can use the Advanced Startup option from within Windows to access the firmware.  The only alternative is to fail to boot Windows more than three times.